# Getting Ref values of component's inner div to programattically set scroll properties when testing with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ref

I'm trying to test a carousel which uses the element's `ref` to set the scroll values to in order to scroll the carousel via next and previous buttons.

The implementation works fine but I'm not sure on how to test it.

At the time the component mounts, the offset and child node values are not set. I would really appreciate if anyone could direct me on how to at least mock these ref properties so that the code can be tested.

Following is a sample code on my approach.

Component.js

```
class PaginatedScroll extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getRef = this.getRef.bind(this);
    this.elm = null;
  }
 
  getRef(elm) {
    this.elm = elm;
  }

  handleNextClick() {
    const { offsetLeft, offsetWidth, childNodes } = this.elm;
    const nextScroll = {scroll next logic}
    this.elm.scrollLeft = nextScroll;
  }

  handlePrevClick() {
    const { offsetLeft, offsetWidth, childNodes } = this.elm;
    const prevScroll = {scroll prev logic}
    this.elm.scrollLeft = prevScoll;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <span>{this.props.title}</span>
      <button onClick={this.handlePrevClick} />
      <div ref={getRef}>
        {this.props.cards}
      </div>
     <button onClick={this.handleNextClick} />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Test.js

```
describe('test nav and nav dots', () => {
    const SampleCard = styled.div`
      width: 300px;
      height: 500px;
    `;

    it('should display scrollable carousel', () => {
      const wrapper = mount(
        <PaginatedScroll
          title="Scrollable carousel"
          cards={
            <>
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
              <SampleCard />
            </>
          }
        />,
      );

      expect(wrapper.find('[data-id="pagination_left"]')).toHaveLength(1);
      expect(wrapper.find('[data-id="pagination_right"]')).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
```

the following is the ref value I get from the test and doesnt include `offsetLeft, offsetWidth, childNodes` properties and the calculations fail.

```
 <ref *1> HTMLDivElement {
      '__reactInternalInstance$715csgs2xis': <ref *2> FiberNode {
        tag: 5,
        key: null,
        elementType: 'div',
        type: 'div',
        stateNode: [Circular *1],
        return: FiberNode {
          tag: 5,
          key: null,
          elementType: 'div',
          type: 'div',
          stateNode: [HTMLDivElement],
          return: [FiberNode],
          child: [Circular *2],
          sibling: [FiberNode],
          index: 1,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: [Object],
          memoizedProps: [Object],
          updateQueue: null,
          memoizedState: null,
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 0,
          nextEffect: null,
          firstEffect: [Circular *2],
          lastEffect: [Circular *2],
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: null,
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 135,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: [FiberNode],
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null
        },
        child: FiberNode {
          tag: 1,
          key: null,
          elementType: [Function],
          type: [Function],
          stateNode: [StyledComponent],
          return: [Circular *2],
          child: [FiberNode],
          sibling: [FiberNode],
          index: 0,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: {},
          memoizedProps: {},
          updateQueue: [Object],
          memoizedState: [Object],
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 1,
          nextEffect: null,
          firstEffect: null,
          lastEffect: null,
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: null,
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 141,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: null,
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null
        },
        sibling: null,
        index: 1,
        ref: [Function: bound ],
        pendingProps: {
          className: 'paginated-carousel-recommendations',
          children: [Object]
        },
        memoizedProps: {
          className: 'paginated-carousel-recommendations',
          children: [Object]
        },
        updateQueue: null,
        memoizedState: null,
        dependencies: null,
        mode: 0,
        effectTag: 128,
        nextEffect: FiberNode {
          tag: 1,
          key: null,
          elementType: [Function],
          type: [Function],
          stateNode: [PaginatedScroll],
          return: [FiberNode],
          child: [FiberNode],
          sibling: null,
          index: 0,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: [Object],
          memoizedProps: [Object],
          updateQueue: null,
          memoizedState: [Object],
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 5,
          nextEffect: [FiberNode],
          firstEffect: [Circular *2],
          lastEffect: [Circular *2],
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: null,
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 130,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: [FiberNode],
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null
        },
        firstEffect: null,
        lastEffect: null,
        expirationTime: 0,
        childExpirationTime: 0,
        alternate: null,
        actualDuration: 0,
        actualStartTime: -1,
        selfBaseDuration: 0,
        treeBaseDuration: 0,
        _debugID: 139,
        _debugSource: null,
        _debugOwner: FiberNode {
          tag: 1,
          key: null,
          elementType: [Function],
          type: [Function],
          stateNode: [PaginatedScroll],
          return: [FiberNode],
          child: [FiberNode],
          sibling: null,
          index: 0,
          ref: null,
          pendingProps: [Object],
          memoizedProps: [Object],
          updateQueue: null,
          memoizedState: [Object],
          dependencies: null,
          mode: 0,
          effectTag: 5,
          nextEffect: [FiberNode],
          firstEffect: [Circular *2],
          lastEffect: [Circular *2],
          expirationTime: 0,
          childExpirationTime: 0,
          alternate: null,
          actualDuration: 0,
          actualStartTime: -1,
          selfBaseDuration: 0,
          treeBaseDuration: 0,
          _debugID: 130,
          _debugSource: null,
          _debugOwner: [FiberNode],
          _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
          _debugNeedsRemount: false,
          _debugHookTypes: null
        },
        _debugIsCurrentlyTiming: false,
        _debugNeedsRemount: false,
        _debugHookTypes: null
      },
      '__reactEventHandlers$715csgs2xis': {
        className: 'paginated-carousel-recommendations',
        children: {
          '$$typeof': Symbol(react.element),
          type: Symbol(react.fragment),
          key: null,
          ref: null,
          props: [Object],
          _owner: null,
          _store: {}
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but maybe instead of mount() use render(), the offsets values are able when the component is drawn.
https://reactjs.org/docs/test-utils.html